How to read the entire console buffer in Windows 11
I wrote a utility originally with Windows 7, which reads the entire console buffer and creates a text file with its contents. A stripped down version (no filing) is shown below, compiled as 32-bit with MSVC 2022.
On that machine the console buffer has 300 lines. The program outputs the following:

width  = 80
depth  = 300
buflen = 24000
nread  = 24000

Now, on a Windows 11 machine the console buffer is about 9000 lines, which can be verified by scrolling up. Yet only the current viewport is captured, and the output here is:

width  = 80
depth  = 25
buflen = 2000
nread  = 2000

I tried requesting more bytes to be read, but nread is still 2000. I've tried both GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() and GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx() which give the same result.
Microsoft warns that ReadConsoleOutputCharacter should no longer be used, but is still supported. I also tried the sample code given by Scrolling a Screen Buffer's Window. This carries a similar warning, and again it works on Windows 7 but not on Windows 11.
The warnings advise using virtual terminal control sequences, but I don't see how they can be used to read the buffer.
How does one read the contents of the whole console buffer in Windows 11? Is it restricted by tighter security?
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
    
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
void fail(const char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}
    
int main(void) {
    // fill the console buffer
    for(int i = 10000; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    
    // get the console handle
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        fail("Unable to get console handle");
    
    // get the console sizing
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info = {0};
    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &info))
    //CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX info = { sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX) };
    //if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info))
        fail("Cannot get console size");
    size_t width = info.dwSize.X;
    size_t depth = info.dwSize.Y;
    
    // allocate memory
    size_t buflen = width * depth;
    LPTSTR buf = malloc(buflen);
    if(buf == NULL)
        fail("Cannot allocate buffer memory");
    
    // collect the console buffer
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD nread = 0;
    if(!ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, buf, buflen, coord, &nread))
        fail("Cannot read console buffer");
    
    // results
    printf("width  = %zu\n", width);
    printf("depth  = %zu\n", depth);
    printf("buflen = %zu\n", buflen);
    printf("nread  = %zu\n", (size_t)nread);
    
    // output to file . . . removed
    
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}


OK, not sure what the root cause is exactly.   I do know the windows console changed for windows 11 -- "the default console is now "Windows Terminal," replacing the traditional "Command Prompt" as the primary interface for accessing command line..."  And I recall that you can ( luckily ) change that behavior in windows settings.  Please dig into it -- this might not be a code problem.  Looks like your code is correct: dwSize is the proper structure member for getting the buffer size.

@gregspears I'm thinking this is perhaps a security enhancement, to retain some legacy compatibility but prevent apps from spying on the output of other apps. Also, it's complicated by Windows 11 providing two different command shells.

I did find a code bug -- the buffer wasn't large enough:  buflen should be computed as buflen = width * depth * sizeof(CHAR_INFO);   (The CHAR_INFO screen info is about 4 bytes per character).  Anyway -- sorry -- that did not fix!  I get error "Cannot read console buffer" at runtime under default windows 11 install.  I believe it's as you said -- security issue.  Sorry I cannot dig more rt now ... family is on the way over.  Merry Christmas Weather Vane and all!

@gregspears that's not the problem, but when I "dig into it" I found that the utility works with administrator privilege. So I would always have to work like that, seeing as the utility is useful in hindsight.

I got the new code to work by just double-clking from file explorer -- will post code post haste

@gregspears the code is suposed to work retrospectively, after the output has been made, when I need to capture it on those 'occasions'. The 9000 lines printed artificially set up known buffer state. Obviously the previous content won't be there.

Understood.  Latest code does work per that requirement: the screen populates with 9000 lines and then the buffer is captured.  I've adhered to your original code as rigorously as possible . . . my usual modus operandi whenever possible and practical.

What I mean is, that the screen should not be populated, but preserve its original content from other programs' output.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This code is tested successfully compiling in MS Visual C and by running in a default Windows 11 OS install and Windows 10, too.  Per my finding, not enough memory was allocated at runtime.  The memory needed for the windows console buffer is computed:
UPDATED -- TCHAR:
buff_size = buffer_hgt * buffer_wdth * sizeof(TCHAR);

Pls see ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() concerning nLength [in] parameter.  ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() does not capture character attributes ( as I previously erroneously thought ) -- but it does expect buffer capability to hold length * sizeof(TCHAR).  TCHAR may (and often does) exceed 1 byte.
This new computation is the only significant change to the code, and it would not run until I made this buffer size correction. After numerous code adjustments and re-tests, the buffer size does appear to be root cause of the initial issue.
NOTES:  Please note ( and apologies ) that this code is not portable and is specific to the MS windows OS per the question tag and OP's code and request.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
    
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
void fail(const char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}
    
int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    HANDLE hConsole;
    LPTSTR buf;
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD nread = 0, buflen, width, depth;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info = {0};

    // fill the console buffer
    for(i = 10000; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    
    // get the console handle
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        fail("Unable to get console handle");
    
    // get the console sizing
    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &info))
        fail("Cannot get console size");
    width = info.dwSize.X;
    depth = info.dwSize.Y;
    
    // allocate memory
    buflen =  width * depth;

    // GS UPDATE: factor in sizeof(TCHAR)
    buf = malloc(buflen * sizeof(TCHAR));  
    if(buf == NULL)
        fail("Cannot allocate buffer memory");
    
    // collect the console buffer
    // Note that parameter buflen still wants to be a product of only  
    //  width and height -- sizeof(TCHAR) is Not a factor.
    if(!ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, buf, buflen, coord, &nread))
        fail("Cannot read console buffer");
    
    // results
    printf("width  = %lu\n", width);
    printf("depth  = %lu\n", depth);
    printf("buflen = %lu\n", buflen);
    printf("nread  = %lu\n", (size_t)nread);
    printf("sizeof(TCHAR) = %lu\n", sizeof(TCHAR)); //GS Added
    
    // output to file . . . removed
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}


Thanks, and Happy Christmas! I have to go too and will look at this soon.

Thanks very much for your input: I only needed to have opened the console in Admin mode. If you were able to run the code on Windows 10, that is not Windows 11, which has additional security enhancements.

Please forgive -- one more (hopefully last) update.  You are correct that ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() does not collect attribute data as I previously, erroneously thought.   However, it does require buffer capability to hold length * sizeof(TCHAR) -- and TCHAR is often greater than a single byte.  This latest update includes a printf()  to display sizeof(TCHAR).  If you don't care to run the latest update NO-ONE can blame you for that at all -- you've been very patient -- appreciated.  On my system, sizeof(TCHAR() == 2 under Win 10 & 11.  Bottom line: larger buffer seems cause for success

Thanks. In my system TCHAR is size 1. I'd overlooked that ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() takes a LPTSTR and not a LPCSTR but I never use wide characters.

Thanks so much for taking a 2nd look!  Yea, I never use wide characters either, and so I was really surprised when my console reported sizeof(TCHAR() == 2  in Win10 & 11 (???)  Need to take another look at my compiler settings . . .   Well, I guess that's it then -- thanx again.
